# Javascript else if everything else?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, innerhtml

I want to use the else if statement to have everything else that is entered.
I thought leaving it blank would work but it doesn't

```
if(answer == "hello") {
  document.getElementById('reply').innerHTML="you entered hello";
}
else if(answer == "goodbye")
  {
    document.getElementById('reply').innerHTML="you entered goodbye";
  }
  else if(answer == "ANYTHING ELSE ENTERED")
  {
    document.getElementById('reply').innerHTML="You entered something else";
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use just else, no else if needed. It means, that both conditions(provided in `if`, `else if`) are false.

```
  else
  {
    document.getElementById('reply').innerHTML="You entered something else";
  }
```

Leaving the string empty means that nothing has entered to the field.

Comment: Okay, thank you... I was thinking there would be an else if so 'if' anything else was entered then the code is executed... thanks!

Comment: Yea, glad you got it working. Please mark my answer accepted by clicking green checkmark below vote count :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `else` without the `if`

```
else 
{
   document.getElementById('reply').innerHTML="You entered something else";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use else without else if:

```
if (condition) {

}
else
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps you,

```
    if (condition1)
      {
      code to be executed if condition1 is true
      }
    else if (condition2)
      {
      code to be executed if condition2 is true
      }
    else
      {
      code to be executed if neither condition1 nor condition2 is true
      }
```

To know more about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else